# What is the point of recycling tofu at the tofu plant?

Tags: always-sometimes-monsters

In the game Always Sometimes Monsters, you can choose to work at a tofu plant or a slaughterhouse. If you choose the tofu plant, you have to move soybeans down a conveyor belt to create various soy foods at the end. When you move soybeans into the mulcher, you have a choice of either creating a tofu cube, or recycling tofu. But when you recycle tofu, it's not clear what happens - it gives a weight of recycled tofu, but no cube is produced. What is the point or function of recycling tofu?